# Postfix arguments

Tags: email, postfix, unix, command-line-interface, service

According to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451135/4315597), I may need to set `smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain` in order to get postfix to work correctly for my needs.

My question: Is there a way to modify this setting from the CLI when I run `sudo postfix start`, rather than punching it into the main.cf file?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Good question. I want a workflow that is easily repeatable, which means avoiding instructions to open a text editor if at all possible. I realize that this is not a common scenario -- it's a bit of an oddball question.

Comment: And you think having to pass such an important parameter via a command line option is in any way more reliable then to put it into the config file where it belongs and where you have to do it only once? Also, I believe this is not possible.

Comment: I believe so, in this case. I realize that there are ways to edit that config file programmatically with tools like sed, but that approach seems even more error-prone. Thank you for letting me know that you don't think my approach is possible -- I will start exploring some other options.